# Create array of type and assign it with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable that is an array with the type Club. A function is filling this variable.

```
clubs: [Club];
```

The function:

```
this.authService.getAllClubs().subscribe(
      clubs => {
        var result = [];

        if(clubs.length > 0) {
          for (const club of clubs) {
            let c = club.club;
            let b = new Club(c.id, c.name, false);
            result.push(b);
          }
        }
         this.clubs = result;

      }
    );
```

But I get the following error on this code: (this.clubs = result;)

```
Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[Club]'.ts(2741)
```

How can I make an array with the type club? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why is Club inside of array if it is type `clubs:Club[]`?

Comment: @pc_coder Ehm it needs to be an array what holds items with type club.

Comment: okey but you need to write Club[] which represents of array of Club object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing two different types:

`[Club]`: is a tuple with only one element, a Club

`Club[]`: is an array of Club elements

You should type your result as the correct thing and fix the types so it works properly